# How do i get parent caller

Tags: java, android

Let us say that user opens Twitter app and hits share button for a selected tweet. He then sees my app in the list along with other apps like Gmail, SMS etc.

In OnCreate method of my activity, I process the tweet. Remove short links etc and then call the PostActivity of twitter app. Below code then shows "My tweet" in compose tweet section of twitter app.

```
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                intent1.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.twitter.android","com.twitter.android.PostActivity"));
                intent1.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent1.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"my tweet");
                intent1.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(intent1);
```

What i want to do is ,before i call PostActivity, i need make 100% sure that my activity was called from twitter app.

Comment: [getCallingActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity()) - since i assume you're being started with `startActivityForResult`? The `ComponentName`, if not `null` will identify the package name (app) of the caller, and the activity within that app.

Comment: I cant use it. Because before calling my intent1.setComponent, i need to know that it was twitter app which invoked my app.

Comment: @Jens is right. If your code belongs to the onCreate method, you can do "ComponentName callingName = getCallingActivity()" before your code and decide whether to execute the rest of your code based on this.

Comment: Looks like you guys are not getting me. How do i know who which app called my activity before i call another activity ? In example i mentioned in my question, its twitter app which called my activity and then i call some other activity.

Comment: @Anil is right, his problem cant be solved by #getCallingActivity since the sharing is done via startActivity, not startActivityForResult - the only option left is probably to add a permission to view the activity stack & check what twitter app is most likely to have called his app.

Comment: @jens Can i implement it with BroadcastReceiver ?